# Error in fstRead R

Tags: r

I am using the new 'fst' package in R for a few weeks to write and read tables in the .fst format. Sometimes I cannot read a table that I've just write having the following message :

```
> tab=read.fst("Tables R/tab.fst",as.data.table=TRUE)
Error in fstRead(fileName, columns, from, to) :  
Unknown type found in column.
```

Do you know why this happens ? Is there an other way to retrieve the table ?